# Clustering with different variables

Tags: cluster-analysis

I've created a list of associations composed of userId's and average times for different sessions:

```
data =
  {<|"userId" -> 5311, "AverageS1Time" -> 4691/9, "AverageS2Time" -> 9489/7, "AverageS3Time" -> 1345.08|>,
   <|"userId" -> 5312, "AverageS1Time" -> 53/2, "AverageS2Time" -> 0, "AverageS3Time" -> 0.|>,
   <|"userId" -> 5313, "AverageS1Time" -> 5, "AverageS2Time" -> 169/2, "AverageS3Time" -> 0|>,
   <|"userId" -> 5314, "AverageS1Time" -> 21958/13, "AverageS2Time" -> 889/10, "AverageS3Time" -> 957.154|>,
   <|"userId" -> 5315, "AverageS1Time" -> 50127/10, "AverageS2Time" -> 302954/17, "AverageS3Time" -> 218.278|>}
```

I would now like to—based on all of the average times in the sessions—find clusters of similar behavior, i.e., finding people who spent similar amounts of time in the same session on average and group them together.

Applying:

```
FindClusters[
 data[All,  
   N[{"userId", "AverageS1Time", "AverageS2Time", "AverageS3Time"}]] // 
  Normal, 5]
```

just gives me a list of clusters dependent on the `userId`.

Could someone give me a hint, how you can cluster based on behavior in different sessions (i.e., average scored time in subsequent sessions over time)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax, which is documented, that clusters one set of elements and returns another set of elements. This is what you'll want to use.

```
elements = #[[{"AverageS1Time", "AverageS2Time", "AverageS3Time"}]] -> # & /@ data;
FindClusters[elements]
```

Comment: Or simply `FindClusters[#[[{"AverageS1Time", "AverageS2Time", "AverageS3Time"}]] -> #[["userId"]] & /@ data]` if you are looking for the clusters of `userId` values. This returns `{{5311, 5314}, {5312, 5313}, {5315}}`.